# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'item' referenced before assignment (python, flask)

Tags: python, flask, runtime-error

**NOTE: NOT A DUPLICATE Because the similar stack-overflow questions did not help me understand the solution to this. Thank you!**

How do I fix this error? I don't understand because I think I did the exact same pattern as in the other method which is not causing problems. I looked at other stackoverflow answers to this and could not figure it out.  Notice how I pass `listOfCheckins=list` in with no problem, but when I try to pass in `checkin=item` it throws this error. (Both are at the very end of their respective functions, in the return statement.)

**Error**:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'item' referenced before assignment. Line: `[session['user_id'], session['user_id'], PER_PAGE]),checkin=item)`

**Snippet of my python flask server *with the problem*:**

```
@app.route('/')
def timeline():
    """Shows a users timeline or if no user is logged in it will
    redirect to the public timeline.  This timeline shows the user's
    messages as well as all the messages of followed users.
    """
    if not g.user:
        return redirect(url_for('public_timeline'))
    #Get info from foursquare
    token = result['access_token_text']
    response = requests.get(FOURSQUARE_API_BASE + "users/self/checkins?oauth_token=" + token + 
        "&v=20150326&m=foursquare")
    dict = json.loads(response.text)
    item = dict['response']['checkins']['items'][0]
    return render_template('timeline.html',messages=query_db('''
        select message.*, user.* from message, user
        where message.author_id = user.user_id and (
            user.user_id = ? or
            user.user_id in (select whom_id from follower
                                    where who_id = ?))
        order by message.pub_date desc limit ?''',
        [session['user_id'], session['user_id'], PER_PAGE]),checkin=item)
```

**Snippet of my python flask server that is causing no problems:**

```
@app.route('/foursquare')
def foursquare():
    """Shows your foursquare info. Or, if you have not authorized this app to connect to 
    foursquare, then it will redirect you to foursquare.
    """
    if not g.user:
        return redirect(url_for('public_timeline'))
    result = query_db('select access_token_text from access_token where user_id = ?',
                          [session['user_id']], one=True)
    if not result:
        return redirect("https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?response_type=code&client_id=" + FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_ID + "&redirect_uri=" + FOURSQUARE_REDIRECT_URI,code=302)
    else:
        #Get info from foursquare
        token = result['access_token_text']
        response = requests.get(FOURSQUARE_API_BASE + "users/self/checkins?oauth_token=" + token + 
            "&v=20150326&m=foursquare")
        dict = json.loads(response.text)
        list = dict['response']['checkins']['items']
        return render_template('foursquare.html', listOfCheckins=list)
```

**timeline.html (Flask template):**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
  {% if request.endpoint == 'public_timeline' %}
    Public Timeline
  {% elif request.endpoint == 'user_timeline' %}
    {{ profile_user.username }}'s Timeline
  {% else %}
    My Timeline
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
  <h2>{{ self.title() }}</h2>
  {% if g.user %}
    {% if request.endpoint == 'user_timeline' %}
      <div class=followstatus>
      {% if g.user.user_id == profile_user.user_id %}
        This is you!
      {% elif followed %}
        You are currently following this user.
        <a class=unfollow href="{{ url_for('unfollow_user', username=profile_user.username)
          }}">Unfollow user</a>.
      {% else %}
        You are not yet following this user.
        <a class=follow href="{{ url_for('follow_user', username=profile_user.username)
          }}">Follow user</a>.
      {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% elif request.endpoint == 'timeline' %}
      <div class=twitbox>
        <h3>What's on your mind {{ g.user.username }}?</h3>
        <form action="{{ url_for('add_message') }}" method=post>
          <p><input type=text name=text size=60><!--
          --><input type=submit value="Share">
        </form>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  <ul class=messages>
  {% if checkin %}
  Most recent checkin:
      <li><strong>Venue:</strong> {{ checkin['venue']['name'] }}<br>
      <strong>Address:</strong> {{ checkin['venue']['location']['address'] }}<br>
      <strong>Shout:</strong> {{ checkin['shout'] }} <br> 
  {% elif g.user %}
  This user has no checkins.    
 {% endif %}
<br>Other Messages: 
  {% for message in messages %}
    <li><img src="{{ message.email|gravatar(size=48) }}"><p>
      <strong><a href="{{ url_for('user_timeline', username=message.username)
      }}">{{ message.username }}</a></strong>
      {{ message.text }}
      <small>&mdash; {{ message.pub_date|datetimeformat }}</small>
  {% else %}
    <li><em>There's no message so far.</em>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that I had 1 tab in front of the "item" line, and 4 spaces in front of the "return" line, so it was treating it in a different scope. The answer was to replace the 4 spaces in front of the "return" line with 1 tab, and then the error went away.

```
item = dict['response']['checkins']['items'][0]
return render_template('timeline.html',messages=query_db('''...
```